# Nested for-each and if-else statement without goto statement

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, foreach, goto

I have a nested for-each and if-else cases like below. In these scenario if the if-else based on the if-else statement I have to go to the starting of the loop or somewhere else in the loop.
Is **GOTO** is the only way to work with this kind of scenarios? or it can be better design?
for brevity I have included only two for-each but in my case I have 4 for-each and around 13 if-else statement.

[image]

Comment: *I have 4 for-each and around 13 if-else statement* sounds like design issues and horrible complexity.

Comment: Break what you are checking and actions into different methods.

Comment: It's people using GOTO in situations like this that is the reason so many people consider it evil.  Such spaghetti code is super hard to understand and follow the flow of code.

Comment: @marcinJuraszek I have multiple condition to validate before doing certain task. it is like if (Computer = started) now check software, hard disk, keyboard.. etc I can not omit them :(

Comment: Use breaks and other functions. GOTO is bad in situations like this, cause a lot of Spaghetti code and makes it hard to understand.

Comment: @DanTeesdale Break will let me out from the current loop/condition but not to the uppermost loop or may be to the inner most one.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Why are you validating the loop once you're well into it?  You simply start out the loop with `if(ComputerStarted() && HardDiskValid() && KeyboardPluggedIn()){DoSomething();}`  If it so happens that one of those validation method requires loops, so be it, but the outer loop need not know or care about it.

Comment: consider reading [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882)

Comment: Break it up into methods, use return values and `out` parameters for control flow, use recursion, use a queue, there are many possible solutions that all depend on what is actually happening in this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method is that long, it is a bad smell. Break it into smaller methods or smaller classes. That will makes it also easier to jump to an other position.

Maybe [state machine principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) will help you to set the next status.

Comment: So... `yield` `return` then?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think so. But maybe in combination with yield break;

Answer (score 3):

Goto is not the only way, but it is probably the cleanest way to do this kind of "multi-level `continue`".  The alternative is to set flags and then check at the top of each loop to see if the appropriate flag is set, but if you do that, you're manipulating state, complicating the code with more `if` conditions, and increasing the possibility of errors.

Consider refactoring, if you can.  The inner loop can probably be refactored into its own method with a `return` statement.

**See Also**
[goto (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx)

> A common use of goto is to transfer control to a specific switch-case
>   label or the default label in a switch statement. The goto statement
>   is also useful to get out of deeply nested loops.